# How to ask for further clarification when I can’t comment

Tags: discussion, answers

How to ask further clarification, or to point out that the answer shown, even if once correct, is not correct anymore? I can’t comment as I don’t have 50 reputation.

Comment: Comments are usually a good way to go about it.  It's also generally a good idea to use a question body to flesh it out, not just repeat the title.

Comment: My reputation is below 50 yet...

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll need to refrain from asking for clarification or other commenting activities until you do.  A good way to do so is to propose edits to posts to improve them.

Comment: How do I suggest an edit ?

Comment: [How do suggested edits work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: @vfalcao you have "edit" link below each post.

Comment: You're probably better off writing a single good question or answer than trying to write dozens of edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to ask for clarification?

If you can’t post comments then you can’t ask for clarification. Try to answer questions that don’t need clarification until you can comment.

Or you can even answer your own question. These can help gain reputation. These questions won’t require clarification but make sure your question and answer are still detailed as not everyone viewing your posts know what you are thinking.

### An answer is outdated

You have two options:

- Post a new answer
- Propose an edit

**Post a new answer**

You can post a new answer if the other answers are out of date. This can be especially useful on technology sites. Say an answer is about version 1 but you post an answer about version 2, some people may still use version 1 and want the relevant answer.

**Propose an edit**

If the answer is out of date and **won’t help anybody** you can propose an edit by pressing the Edit button. You can then update the answer.

**NOTE:** Your edit will need to be approved by two users with over 200 reputation (on a graduated site) or a moderator so try to make them substantial.

See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)